# General case of Hermite differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the second-order linear differential equation $x''+a(t)x'+b(t)x=0$, with $a(t)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nt^n$ and $b(t)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_nt^n$.

> (1) Determine conditions that a sequence $(c_n)_n$ must satisfy in order for the corresponding infinite series $\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n$ to be a solution of $x''+a(t)x'+b(t)x=0$.

> (2) Show that if $(c_n)_n$ satisfies these conditions and the series $\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n$ is convergent, then the sum $x(t)$ satisfies $x''+a(t)x'+b(t)x=0$.

> (3) Solve the Hermite differential equation $x''−2tx'+x=0$.

My attempt for (1):

Let $x=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n$ and $\sum^\infty_{m=0}d_mt^m$, with $d_0=1$ and $d_m=0$ $\forall m\ge1$. Then the equation becomes $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}n(n-1)c_nt^{n-2}+a(t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}nc_nt^{n-1}+b(t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)c_nt^{n-2}+a(t)\sum^\infty_{n=1}nc_nt^{n-1}+b(t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}t^n+a(t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)c_{n+1}t^n+b(t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nt^n=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{n=0}\big[(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}t^n\sum^\infty_{m=0}d_mt^m+(n+1)c_{n+1}t^n\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_mt^m+c_nt^n\sum^\infty_{m=0}b_mt^m\big]=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{m=0}\big[(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}d_m+(n+1)c_{n+1}a_m+c_nb_m\big]t^{n+m}=0$$

Now to satisfy the last expression I would say that the term inside the quadras is equal to $0$, but is this always right? I thought that since I have two indices $n,m$, maybe some terms, or all, vanish, so what is right approach from here?